# Slow NIntegrate over complicated domains (sometimes)

Tags: performance-tuning, numerical-integration, piecewise

This is no longer a problem with Mathematica 10.* where I can use regions to do the integrations

**Overview**

I have a very large matrix I need to calculate where each element requires the integration of a product of two functions over some complicated domain. I would like to find a set of options for `NIntegrate` that will work well for all of my integrations. Most of the integrations take only seconds but others take up to 4 hours. Below is a histogram of timing for the integrations. It is clear that there are some very fast one and some very slow ones:
[image: Histogram of <code>NIntegrate</code> timing]

The following set of plots shows six integrands that took less than 15m along with a visualization of the domain. The plot label shows how long it took to integrate.
[image: Example functions that takes less than 15m to integrate]

The following set of plots shows six integrands that took more than 15m along with a visualization of the domain. The plot label shows how long it took to integrate.
[image: Example functions that takes more than 15m to integrate]

As you can see the two groups do not look much different however all of the ones that take a long time results in integrated values that are very close to zero ($\approx 10^{-16}$).

**Details**

Here are the functions for the forth plot in each set shown above:

A good one (fast):

```
 rg={{-3.35513, 5.30513}, {-1.51554, 7.14471}};

 funa=Function[{x, y}, E^(1/2 (-(0.39 + x/5) (100. (0.39 + x/5) - 
   6.12323*10^-15 (0. + y/5)) - (-6.12323*10^-15 (0.39 + x/5) + 
   50. (0. + y/5)) (0. + y/5)))]

 funb=Function[{x, y}, E^(1/2 (-(-0.195 + x/5) (55.3571 (-0.195 + x/5) + 
   15.4647 (-0.562917 + y/5)) - (15.4647 (-0.195 + x/5) + 
   94.6429 (-0.562917 + y/5)) (-0.562917 + y/5)))]

 region=Function[{x,y}, ((1/2 (4.54663 - 0.909327 x - 0.525 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (0.954793 - 1.05 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (-2.63705 + 0.909327 x - 0.525 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (-2.63705 + 0.909327 x + 0.525 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (0.954793 + 1.05 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (4.54663 - 0.909327 x + 0.525 y) >= 
   0) || (1/2 (3.45544 - 0.909327 x - 0.525 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (2.04599 - 1.05 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (-0.454663 + 0.909327 x - 0.525 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (-1.54586 + 0.909327 x + 0.525 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (-0.136399 + 1.05 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (2.36425 - 0.909327 x + 0.525 y) >= 
   0) || (1/2 (2.36425 - 0.909327 x - 0.525 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (-0.136399 - 1.05 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (-1.54586 + 0.909327 x - 0.525 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (-0.454663 + 0.909327 x + 0.525 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (2.04599 + 1.05 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (3.45544 - 0.909327 x + 0.525 y) >= 
   0) || (1/2 (2.04599 - 0.909327 x - 0.525 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (3.45544 - 1.05 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (2.36425 + 0.909327 x - 0.525 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (-0.136399 + 0.909327 x + 0.525 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (-1.54586 + 1.05 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (-0.454663 - 0.909327 x + 0.525 y) >= 
   0) || (1/2 (0.954793 - 0.909327 x - 0.525 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (4.54663 - 1.05 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (4.54663 + 0.909327 x - 0.525 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (0.954793 + 0.909327 x + 0.525 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (-2.63705 + 1.05 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (-2.63705 - 0.909327 x + 0.525 y) >= 
   0) || (1/2 (-0.136399 - 0.909327 x - 0.525 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (2.36425 - 1.05 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (3.45544 + 0.909327 x - 0.525 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (2.04599 + 0.909327 x + 0.525 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (-0.454663 + 1.05 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (-1.54586 - 0.909327 x + 0.525 y) >= 
   0) || (1/2 (-0.454663 - 0.909327 x - 0.525 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (-1.54586 - 1.05 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (-0.136399 + 0.909327 x - 0.525 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (2.36425 + 0.909327 x + 0.525 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (3.45544 + 1.05 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (2.04599 - 0.909327 x + 0.525 y) >= 
   0) || (1/2 (-1.54586 - 0.909327 x - 0.525 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (-0.454663 - 1.05 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (2.04599 + 0.909327 x - 0.525 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (3.45544 + 0.909327 x + 0.525 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (2.36425 + 1.05 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (-0.136399 - 0.909327 x + 0.525 y) >= 
   0) || (1/2 (-2.63705 - 0.909327 x - 0.525 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (-2.63705 - 1.05 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (0.954793 + 0.909327 x - 0.525 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (4.54663 + 0.909327 x + 0.525 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (4.54663 + 1.05 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (0.954793 - 0.909327 x + 0.525 y) >= 
   0)) && ! ((-2.75 + x)^2 + (0. + y)^2 <= 
  0.316406 || (1.375 + x)^2 + (-2.38157 + y)^2 <= 
  0.316406 || (1.375 + x)^2 + (2.38157 + y)^2 <= 0.316406)]
```

A Bad one (slow):

```
 rg={{2.9, 5.}, {-1.05, 1.05}};

 funa=Function[{x, y}, E^(1/2 (-(0. + 100. (-0.39 + x/5)) (-0.39 + x/5) 
     - (0. +   50. (0. + y/5)) (0. + y/5)))]

 funb=Function[{x, y}, 1.90476 (0. + y)]

 region=Function[{x, y}, 
  1/2 (4.54663 - 0.909327 x - 0.525 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (0.954793 - 1.05 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (-2.63705 + 0.909327 x - 0.525 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (-2.63705 + 0.909327 x + 0.525 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (0.954793 + 1.05 y) >= 0 && 
  1/2 (4.54663 - 0.909327 x + 0.525 y) >= 
  0 && (-2.75 + x)^2 + (0. + y)^2 > 0.316406]
```

The ugly integral

```
 NIntegrate[
    Boole[region[x, y]] funa[x, y] funb[x, y], 
    {x, rg[[1, 1]], rg[[1, 2]]}, {y, rg[[2, 1]], rg[[2, 2]]},
    Method->{"SymbolicPiecewiseSubdivision","ExpandSpecialPiecewise"->False,
       Method->"LocalAdaptive"},
    MaxRecursion->50,MinRecursion->20,
    AccuracyGoal->7,PrecisionGoal->6
  ]
```

I have picked `MinRecursion` to be 20 to make sure that the smaller features of the domain are found. (This is just one example of a domain others are more involved with smaller items.) I have used "LocalAdaptive" because I seam to get fewer complaints about slow convergence than when I use "GlobleAdaptive" and finally I use "ExpandSpecialPiecewise"->`False` because there are a few cases where I get an error that I have exceeded the number of piecewise divisions (This dose not appear to be connected with the number of conditions in the domain but instead the divisions done by `NIntegrate`)

I have tried many combinations of options for `NIntegrate` but I have not found one that will work for all [gazillion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_and_fictitious_numbers) matrix elements. I realize it is not possible with the code give to test for all of my cases but I will give good ideas a run in my code and report back.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of an answer:

> This is no longer a problem with Mathematica 10.* where I can use regions to do the integrations  --OP

Comment: Yes, once I got access to Regions things work much better now.